# Getting error on deleted line of code, what is going on here?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I got an error when trying to edit my authorization rules in the web.config file, from code behind. So I removed the faulty code. Still got the error. Thought it might be a bug in visual studio so I restarted. Still got the error. Commented out the entire method and the call to the method. Still get the error.

```
Line 32:            ////authorization.Rules.Set(0, accessRule);
Line 33:            ////configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal); 
Line 34:            "**This is the red marked erroneous line**"
Line 35:  
Line 36:            //StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
```

What black magic is this? There is no code on the line and the line isn't even called and yet I get the error reported as:

> Authorization rule must specify a list of users and/or roles.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException:
>   Authorization rule must specify a list of users and/or roles.
>
> Source File: C:\MyProject\Accounts.aspx.cs    Line: 34

Yet, all code referring to the authorization is commented out, and the method isn't even called. Method:

```cs
public static void WriteAccsToAuth(List<User> allAllowedUsers)
{
    //Configuration configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
    //AuthorizationSection authorization = (AuthorizationSection)configuration.GetSection("system.web/authorization");
    //AuthorizationRule accessRule = new AuthorizationRule(AuthorizationRuleAction.Allow);
    ////foreach (User usr in allAllowedUsers)
    ////{
    ////    accessRule.Users.Add(usr.Domain + "\\" + usr.UserName);
    ////}
    ////Debug.WriteLine("Users count: " + accessRule.Users.Count);
    ////Debug.WriteLine("Rules count: " + authorization.Rules.Count);
    ////authorization.Rules.Set(0, accessRule);
    ////configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);
    "**This is the red marked erroneous line**"

    //StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
    //Debug.WriteLine("Users written to config file. Called by method " + stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name + ".");
}
```

Method call:

```cs
public static void LoadUsers()
{
    ...
    //Accounts.WriteAccsToAuth(dbUsers.ToList());
    ...
}
```

I have tried rebuilding, restarting Visual Studio and restarting IIS. Is my IIS some how caching the error? I mean the commented lines are visible in the error message... I got no clue what is going on here.

Comment: Clean the project and build again will fix the issue

Comment: @un-lucky Actually tried that just before posting, but forgot to add it in the post. However, I just did it again (multiple times) before rebuilding and now it works.... I am really confused.

Comment: @un-lucky actually, now it is spamming `Exception thrown: 'System.Web.HttpException' in System.Web.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Web.HttpException' in System.Web.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Web.HttpException' in System.Web.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Web.HttpException' in System.Web.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Web.HttpException' in System.Web.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Web.HttpException' in System.Web.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Web.HttpException' in System.Web.dll` in the debug output, but no indication of error anywhere. The web app actually starts but is super slow....

Comment: @un-lucky Nevermind... was getting some error in my code. Now everything works. Post an answer if you want the rep. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that its worked, and my suggestions helped. always happy to help without rep.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still confused over why and how this happened, but cleaning the solution and then building it solved the issue.

Comment: I suspect that you had a circular reference, which cause the compiler to freak out because the one DLL isn't deleted and it's requesting certain lines of code to still be there. Just double check that this isn't happening. It's sometimes a good idea to run a build with verbose output as there will be more information around what could be causing this.

Comment: @Cyberwiz How do I run it with verbose output, to double check this? Also getting other random exceptions like `Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll`. Some runs they happen, some they don't. Would be nice with more info.

Comment: under Tools -> Options then choose Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run. On that window you can choose the MSBuild project build output verbosity.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using npm

```
npm cache clean --force
```